# HTTP request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, forms

I'm trying my hand at making api calls with Angular js. Unfortunately, I seem to be having some trouble. I am trying to pass a hero name into a form field and use that information to converse with my backend api. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any response data when I try to make contact. Any tips on how to make a successful call?

Here is the controller.

```
vm.errorMsg = '';

vm.hero = '';

function getCharacter(hero) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        url: "localhost:8080/character/heroByName/" + hero
    }).then(function mySuccess(response){
        vm.hero = response.data;
        console.log(vm.hero);
    }, function myError(response){
        vm.errorMsg = response.statusText;
        console.log(vm.errorMsg);
    });
}
```

Here is the form field, where you can enter a hero name.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>{{character.title}}</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Wolverine" ng-model="character.hero">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="character.getCharacter(character.hero)">Go!</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: turn on debugging tools in your browser and show the actual error. Second
ng-click="character.getCharacter(character.hero)" - character is a controllerAs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expose your function to the scope by assigning it to `vm.getCharacter`. Afterwards you can call it in your template via `ng-click="vm.getCharacter(character.hero)"`.

**Controller**

```
vm.errorMsg = '';
vm.hero = '';
vm.getCharacter = getCharacter;

function getCharacter(hero) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        url: "localhost:8080/character/heroByName/" + hero
    }).then(function mySuccess(response){
        vm.hero = response.data;
        console.log(vm.hero);
    }, function myError(response){
        vm.errorMsg = response.statusText;
        console.log(vm.errorMsg);
    });
}
```

**Template**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="vm.getCharacter(character.hero)">Go!</button>
```